# ¿Como ocultar y mostrar texto html?

Tags: html, jquery, css

tendo un **div** de width 180px que va a tener texto, quiero saber como puedo mostrar en forma de **tooltips** o algo parecido todo el texto cuando estoy con el ratón encima del **div**

```css
    .nombre_archivo{
      width: 180px;
      line-height: 25px;
      float: left;
      text-align: left;
      font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
      font-size: 16px;
      white-space: nowrap;
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
      overflow: hidden;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
```

```html
 <div class="nombre_archivo">nombre del archivooooooooooooooooooooo</div>
```

Comment: Los navegadores muestran cuando colocas el ratón encima de un elemento lo que contenga su atributo `title`, en forma de tooltip.

Comment: Esto te puede ayudar: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_tooltip Cualquier duda comenta

Answer (score 4):

Puedes hacer con CSS con la opción que cuando pases el mouse sobre el texto muestres el mensaje flotante.

```css
 .tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
 visibility: visible;
   }

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: orange;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;

  /* Position the tooltip */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="tooltip">Texto html en la vista
  <span class="tooltiptext">Mensaje en forma de tooltip</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo que dice **PhpMyGuel** en su comentario es muy cierto pero puede hacer algo con `CSS` para mostrar un `tooltips` con estilos, te dejo el siguiente ejemplo:

**Edición**: Modifique el ejemplo cambiando el nombre desde `javascript` o `Jquery` esto lo hice con el evento **hover** de javaScript.

```js
var nameArchivo = 'Nombre del archivo desde JS';

function cambiarTexto() {
   $("#tooltipspan").html(nameArchivo);
}
```

```css
.nombre_archivo {
          position: relative;
          display: inline-block;
          border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
        }

        .nombre_archivo .tooltiptext {
          visibility: hidden;
          width: 120px;
          background-color: #555;
          color: #fff;
          text-align: center;
          border-radius: 6px;
          padding: 5px 0;
          position: absolute;
          z-index: 1;
          bottom: 125%;
          left: 50%;
          margin-left: -60px;
          opacity: 0;
          transition: opacity 0.3s;
        }

        .nombre_archivo .tooltiptext::after {
          content: "";
          position: absolute;
          top: 100%;
          left: 50%;
          margin-left: -5px;
          border-width: 5px;
          border-style: solid;
          border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
        }

        .nombre_archivo:hover .tooltiptext {
          visibility: visible;
          opacity: 1;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <body style="text-align:center;">
        <br><br><br>
        <div class="nombre_archivo" onmouseover="cambiarTexto()"> Nombre del archivoooooooooooo
          <span class="tooltiptext" id="tooltipspan"></span>
        </div>
        <br><br><br>
        <div class="nombre_archivo"> Nombre del archivooooooooooooooooooo
          <span class="tooltiptext">nombre del archivo</span>
        </div>
        </body>
        </html>
```